# powershell get-aduser issues

Tags: powershell, server, active-directory

So I have this line of code that is supposed to return me every user of an AD, issue is, there are two AD, it wroks for one, but not for the other and I have no idea why.
Here are the lines that I got:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Get-ADUser -server "server1.place.com" -Credential $Credential -Filter 'givenName -like "Alan"' -SearchBase "OU=Utilisateurs,OU=random,DC=server1,DC=place,DC=com" 

Get-ADUser -server "server2.place.com"  -Credential $Credential  -Filter 'givenName -like "Alan"' -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=server2,DC=place,DC=COM"
```

Both lines point to where the users are, have the same structure and a similar server name. The filter is normal it is the reduce testing time.

The error that I get is:

```
Get-ADUser : Impossible de contacter le serveur. Il se peut que le serveur n’existe pas, est actuellement hors service ou ne dispose pas des services Web Active Directory.
```

Roughly translating to: server either doesn't exist, is down, or can't handle Web Active Directory.
it takes it issue with the "-sever" part of the line. And only the second get-ADUser does this.

The only other thing that is different is in the srevers, the first one has this in its user folder:[server1 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpSZ8.png)

The second sever however has this:[server2 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jDSi.png)

This will most likely pose problems later but I don't think its related to the server issue.
last piece of info is that the default server is the server1, so when I don't include the -server switch it will automatically go search in server1.

Comment: The built-in `Users` container is not an OU, so its RDN is `CN`, not `OU`: `-SearchBase "CN=Users,DC=server2,DC=place,DC=COM"`

Comment: thing is there are more users that what I'm trying to get, they're all around, I just want the ones that are there. If I understand correctly what your talking about is a sort of  'default' user container.
But if that's the issue why would the server1 work and not the server2?
I think it might have to do with access, I don't have full access and that would explain the different format of both.
but the error I get doesn't mention the path as an issue.